# listview item text is not set in match_parent in dialogframent kotlin

Tags: kotlin, listview, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

Listview show in DialogFragment. Data is perfectly fill in listview. listview item text is not set match_parent. I have get TextView width match_parent but it's show Textview  width is wrap_content.

[image]

Above image Listview set in DialogFragment. List Item Text width set match_parent but its display wrap_content in Yellow border. I was tried to this example without dialogFragment. Listview textview set in match_parent but In DialogFragement Listview Textview Set width match_parent diaplay in warp_content. how to solved its?

dialog_list_view.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#FFD700"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgDialogListClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvDialogListTitle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDialogListTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Select Serve No"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgDialogListClear"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewDialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

dialog_list_item.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvListViewDialogItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

CustomDialog.kt

```
class CustomDialog(val servList: ArrayList<Serve>) : DialogFragment() {

    interface OnInputListener {
        fun sendInput(input: String?)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val inflater = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val binding = DialogListViewBinding.inflate(inflater)

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        val servAdapter = DialogListAdapter(servList, requireContext())
        binding.listViewDialog.adapter = servAdapter
        servAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
        binding.listViewDialog.isClickable = true
        binding.listViewDialog.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->

            val serve = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i) as Serve

            val serve1 = serve.serveNo
            dialog.dismiss()
           /* (activity as AddProduct?)..setText(input)*/
            mOnInputListener?.sendInput(serve1.toString())


            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), serve1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }


        return binding.root
    }

 override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        try {
            mOnInputListener = activity as OnInputListener?
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.message)
        }
    }
}
```

DialogListAdapter.kt

```
class DialogListAdapter (val servNo : ArrayList<Serve>,val context: Context) : BaseAdapter() {
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return  servNo.size
    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Serve = servNo[p0]


    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return  p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val binding = DialogListItemBinding.inflate(inflater)
        val ser = servNo.get(p0)
        binding.tvListViewDialogItem.text = ser.serveNo
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `DialogFragment` code?

Comment: I put DialogFragment code.

Comment: Can you post the `DialogListAdapter` code?

Comment: above put DialogListAdapter  code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method or edit it in your DialogFragment

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val maxWidth = (resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels * .8).toInt()
        dialog?.window?.setLayout(maxWidth, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    }
```

Without this code dialog fragment cannot use match_parent width into list items.
You can use same method to set also the dialog height.